# JavascriptCore Objective-C + Crypto

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, javascriptcore

I need to use randomBytes / getRandomValues from crypto in JSCore inside Objective-C. Passing it through a JSContext callback is too slow / has way too much overhead. Is there any native js function (no access to window.crypto either), that can help me do this?